# Perl daemon to handle socket and websocket

Tags: perl, sockets, websocket

I would like to add websocket support to my daemon which is already running as socket server. Do I need to use threads ?

Here is the loop for incoming socket connections

```
while (not $signal)
{
    # waiting for a new client connection
    my $client_socket = $socket->accept();

    # get information about a newly connected client
    try {
        my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
        my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
        syslog("Connection from $client_address:$client_port");

        # read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
        my $data = "";
        $client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
        syslog("Received data: $data") if ($debug == 1);

        # write response data to the connected client
        my $resp_data = "ok";
        $client_socket->send($resp_data);

        # notify client that response has been sent
        shutdown($client_socket, 1);

        # parse command received
        parse_cmd($data);
    }
    catch
    {
        syslog("Error receiving data");
    }
}
```

Comment: First you should be able to differentiate between plain socket and websocket requests. Does it makes sense to run multiple protocols on the same port?

Comment: I do not plan to run them on same port. The goal is to communicate using TCP with my home automation box (already running since years) and to communicate with a nodemcu device using websocket

Comment: You might want to check https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Writing-websocket-chat-using-Mojolicious-Lite